# If statements in autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I would like a hotkey that opens Chrome when I hold the windows key and press "c". This is what I have written:

```
#c::Run chrome.exe
```

however, if chrome is already open, I would like it to activate that window instead. The example of such a script given in the beginner's tutorial is this

```
    IfWinExist Untitled - Notepad
{
    WinActivate
}
else
{
    Run Notepad
    WinWait Untitled - Notepad
    WinActivate
}
```

Unfortunately, the name of any Chrome window is (current website) - Google Chrome so I need to know how to use some kind of universal name for my Chrome windows so that it will recognise them as the one program. Any help is appreciated. I am total noob

Comment: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ahk_class` of the window instead, it's like a unique identifier for the window. You can get it by right-clicking the autohotkey icon in your taskbar, selecting "Window Spy" then clicking on Chrome and copying the `ahk_class`.

```
if (WinExist("ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1"))
    WinActivate, % "ahk_id " WinExist("ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1")
else {
    MsgBox, Run Google Chrome
    ;Run, chrome.exe?
}
```